# 'View cannot be shared by more than one ListView' System.Windows..ListView

Tags: wpf, listview, gridview, dynamic

I'm trying to set the View for my `ListView` dynamically: But I get an Exception '**View cannot be shared by more than one `ListView`'** although I'm using it only once. 
Anyways if I make an instance already, and then the `DataTrigger` triggers, the Exception takes place too.

This is my wpf code:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}" SelectionMode="Extended" AlternationCount="2" >
    <ListView.Style>
        <Style>
            <Setter Property="ListView.View" Value="{StaticResource MyView1}" />
            <Style.Triggers>                
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=MyPath1}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="ListView.View" Value="{StaticResource MyView2}" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=MyPath2}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="ListView.View" Value="{StaticResource MyView3}" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListView.Style>
</ListView>
```

and this is from Resources:

```
<GridView x:Key="MyView1">
    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=MyProperty}" >
        <GridViewColumnHeader Content="Text" />
    </GridViewColumn>
</GridView>
..
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `DynamicResource` rather than `StaticResource`.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4149544/wpf-setting-listview-view-via-datatrigger) for full code.

Comment: This works for me too.. 2 conditions: DynamicResource + initial View definition - trigger all templates with DataTrigger

Answer (score 7):

You can add the x:Shared="False" attribute to your GridView resources like this

```
<GridView x:Key="MyView1" x:Shared="False">
    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=MyProperty}" > 
        <GridViewColumnHeader Content="Text" /> 
    </GridViewColumn> 
</GridView> 
..
```

**Update**

Uploaded sample project [here](http://www.mediafire.com/?c6idme6retwsylp)

Comment: Hmm, it works fine for me when I add it. Uploaded a sample project